# How To give Pagination to asp:DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my ASPX code, however, I can't see any way to do Pagination

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlProjectImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3"
              RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" BorderWidth="0px"
              HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <ItemStyle />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" valign="top">
            <tr>
                <td width="16" align="center" valign="top"></td>

               <td width="169" height="132" align="center" valign="middle" class="top-links01">
                    <a href="Project_Details.aspx?id_Project=<%# Eval("id_Project")%>&type=<%= Request.Params["type"]%>&activity=<%=Request.Params["activity"]%>">
                        <img id="findme" alt="" height="114" src="<%# Eval("Thumbnail_Image") %>" title="Click To View Project Details" border="0" /></a>
                </td>
                <td width="16" align="center" valign="top"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProject_name" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("Project_Name") %>' CssClass="top-links01" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center"><img src="/images/clear.gif" border="0" height="20px" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

What am I missing that will allow me to do pagination?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PagedDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx) to page a data-list. See [this article](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/697-pagination-repeater-datalist-control-asp-net.aspx) which explain the same in detail.

On the related note, why not use [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) instead - it can be used with [DataPager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.aspx) for paging and offers complete control over the markup generated.

Answer (score 0):

Mayu,

I don't think you can do pagination using DataList. You either have to implement it manually by following the article link mentioned by VinayC or switch to GridView as it does pagination for you.

Look at [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagecount.aspx)